# VB Wildcard filepath filesystem.dir match

Tags: vb.net, listbox, wildcard, file-search

Attempting to create a program that will find a folder in a directory based upon a wildcard search and result all files found to a listbox. I seem to be having some problems with it finding a folder that is like the input name from a textbox.

For a ridiculous example:
*Textbox entry is "Cats and D"

Filename = "\Cats and Dogs Funnies\"

the file is filled with a bunch of great cat and dog pictures and videos (in separate sub folders) and I want to put the videos in a listbox as .fullname that is obtained when clicking a button*

The hangup I seem to be having (besides being sloppy and somewhat new at this) is obtaining the found result that matches the wildcard' folder. Below is the stripped down version of my script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[ VB ]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim tbxCont, fipath As String  
Dim di As System.IO.DirectoryInfo  
Dim diar As System.IO.FileInfo

tbxCont = TextBox1.Text
fipath = "C:Users\RandomUser\Desktop\" 

If txbCont = Nothing Then  
MsgBox("Please provide a name",MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)  
Exit Sub  
Else  
If FileSystem.Dir(fipath & txbCont.Substring(0, txbCont.Length - 4) & "*", FileAttribute.Directory) <> "" Then  
di = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(fipath & txbCont.Substring(0, txbCont.Length - 4) & "*" & "\Videos\")
For Each diar In di.GetFiles("*", searchOption:=IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)  
FileList.Items.Add(diar.FullName)  
Next  
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

It does not seem to be using the wildcard to find a like file. Is there a better way I could be going about this? Or, possibly obtain the found result from what has been found?

Much Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `Filename = "\Cats and Dogs Funnies\"` means `DirectoryName= "Cats and Dogs Funnies"`.

You should first check whether the search pattern a user has provided can map to an existing Directory.
If it does not, inform that the partial path entered can't be found and return.
If it exists, add the "Videos" subfolder to the Path, list all the files this combined path contains and add the files FullName to a ListBox Control.

(Of course, some error handling is needed, first of all to verify that the a directory filter using wildcards is actually returning the desired results).

This is a possible solution:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Please provide a name", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim txtCont As String = "*" & TextBox1.Text & "*"
Dim DirectoryBase As String = "C:\Users\RandomUser\Desktop\"

Dim DirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(DirectoryBase)
Dim dInfoSearchFolder As DirectoryInfo =
    DirInfo.GetDirectories(txtCont, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault

If IsNothing(dInfoSearchFolder) Then
    'Notify that the search path was not found
End If

dInfoSearchFolder = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(dInfoSearchFolder.FullName, "Videos"))
FileList.Items.AddRange(dInfoSearchFolder.GetFiles().Select(Function(f) f.FullName).ToArray())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Jimi. In applying the above it now thinks my searching directory is "C:\Videos". The file structure I am going for in this scenario would be "C:\Users\\[UserName]\Desktop\Cats and Dogs Funnies\Videos\" but I would like to be able to type a partial name like "Cats and D" into my text box to result this file.

Comment: @buelianvaluz  As I wrote: *some error handling is needed*. You have to provide an actual (existing) path for `DirectoryBase`. The one specified in the code right now is a makeshift path. Nothing checks if this hard-coded path is valid. Which is the path you have inserted? Also, use the code how it is, so we are on the same page if something has to be adjusted.

Comment: @buelianvaluz Then `DirectoryBase` should be `C:\Users\[UserName]\Desktop`

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @buelianvaluz  Write down the actual path you're using for `DirectoryBase`.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! The actual path I am seeing to reach is _C:\Users\Default\Desktop\Cats and Dogs Funnies\Videos_ as the full file path. The path I am currently using for `DirectoryBase = "C:\Users\Default\Desktop"`

Comment: @buelianvaluz  And does that directory actually exist (`C:\Users\Default\Desktop`)? Is there a user named "Default"? If this path exists and it's accessible (with the current user rights), this code should work as it is.

Comment: @buelianvaluz  Very well. I'm glad you got it to work :)

Comment: However, does not accept a partial input "Cats and" into textbox. I'll do some google searching to find out how to do this.

Comment: @buelianvaluz  Yes, it does. Are you sure you have copied the code exactly as it is? Note that the "*" (asterisk) is added to the textbox text, both sides of the text. If you have changed that, it won't work. Don't insert asterisks in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Jimi with edit for wildcard search

```
If TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Please provide a name", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim txtCont As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length() - 1) & "*"
Dim DirectoryBase As String = "C:\Users\RandomUser\Desktop\"

Dim DirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(DirectoryBase)
Dim dInfoSearchFolder As DirectoryInfo =
    DirInfo.GetDirectories(txtCont, SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault

If IsNothing(dInfoSearchFolder) Then
    'Notify that the search path was not found
End If

dInfoSearchFolder = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(dInfoSearchFolder.FullName, "Videos"))
FileList.Items.AddRange(dInfoSearchFolder.GetFiles().Select(Function(f) f.FullName).ToArray())
```